# TYPO3 Dumy package does not show installation screen

Tags: web, wamp, typo3

I am trying to install the Dummy package to my laptop.

I have installed `WAMP` and i have placed the dummy package into the WWW directory.

However when i go to my `Localhost` from `WAMP` and click on the dummy page, instead of showing me the installation screen it shows my the directory index.

[image: when i click on the localhost from WAMP]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dummy package has no sources inside, you can see, there's no even `index.php` file.

Use `Source + Dummy` which will give you an empty TYPO3 system or even better `Introduction Package` for learning purposes - working and containing lot of samples.

To create `ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL` make sure that your system displays files' names with extension ie: open with the `Windows Explorer` folder where you unziped the package and make sure that it can see filenames as `INSTALL.txt` (not only `INSTALL`) if it doesn't you need to search in options of Windows Explorer...)

Then go to folder `typo3conf` and create just common, empty file  `ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL.txt` and finally chane it's name and remove `.txt` extension.

TYPOe install tool will be satisfied.

Comment: hey thank you were absolutely right! One more question, it says that I should create new file "Create a file called ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL in the folder typo3conf" I have trying this before, but the question is how to create a new fie. In windows there is not create new file inside the documents? Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: 'biesior' Biesiorof  Man you are the greatest, thank you so much, everything worked as it should!!!

Answer (score 2):

to create ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL just use command line

win+r -> type cmd -> navigate to directory -> type: echo > ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL

Comment: do you have any idea why it would not let me add this "userfunctions.php" file name in the file directory.?

Comment: @Eircman what are you talking about ? This topic afaik is about missing sources and enable_install_tool. What file userfunxions.php has to do with it ? Pls next problem = next topic. Descibe it and don`t just throw questions

Comment: You are right I apologize for that. Thanx for the help though!! This is the answer in its own topic" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918238/userfunctions-php-why-i-cant-add-this-file-in-typo3-fileadmin "