# userfunctions.php why I can't add this file in Typo3 fileadmin/

Tags: php, web, typo3

I am following a tutorial how to create modern templates using typo3.[the website with the tutorial](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/tutorials/doc_tut_templselect/0.1.0/view/1/2/)
I am instructed to add a php file under the in fileadmin/userfunctions.php, but for some reason Typo3 says that this file is not allowed> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red error is more than enought to answer your question

php extension is not allowed to upload. Just add the file manualy to the directory. By clickng to the folder nat via web panel

Comment: hey thanks for the help, I am not very sure I understand the solution though. Sorry I am a very newbie as you can see :(

Comment: I know you must hate my by now:)  but there is no paste options in the fileadmin/ I copy the file from my computer, and then try to paste but there is not such an option.

Comment: Ok now I get what you meant, I thought you wanted me to do it wab based, but you meant in my file directory into my computer. Ok I managed to do it, thanx allot!!

Answer (score 0):

It is sometimes because of BE allowed file extension.

1. Go to TYPO3 Backend
2. Install Tool All Configuration
3. [textfile_ext] -> check this input box whether php,  php3, phtml are
   listed in this box or not. If no, include them.